Parallel State Machines as an Analog To Quantum Computing
I recently got into Michael Sipser's Introduction to the Theory of Computation. I've only done software a couple years professionally, but in that time have spent a lot of time thinking about state machines. The book has cultivated a sense of wonder for them.
Per my rookie understanding, a non-deterministic state machine is one that run copies of itself in parallel, until one of the copies achieves a success state. We don't know the output until we achieve a success state, and the machine returns from its execution, at which point its copies 'disappear' or are discarded.
This seems like the general idea behind quantum computing? We use particles as our state machines, set the same initial conditions, and 'entangle' them in such a way that they all need to enter different states and cant be in each others'. Once one achieves a success state, we stop and measure it? Or the wave function collapses? Somehow we get the result out of the system, and the other machines/particles are discarded.
All that to say, is this the right path of thinking? Its probably clear I don't have much rigor here, I didn't get a degree in either of these things. But it's been fascinating thinking about parallels.
